# Is there a way to write a hive script for the expected output

Tags: hadoop, hive

log1

```
event1   foo_id1
event1   foo_id2
event1   foo_id3
event1   foo_id4
event1   foo_id1
event1   foo_id1
event1   foo_id2
event1   foo_id1
event1   foo_id1
event1   foo_id3
```

Log2

```
event2      foo_id1     od_id1
event2      foo_id1     od_id13
event2      foo_id1     od_id15
event2      foo_id2     od_id2
event2      foo_id2     od_id14
event2      foo_id3     od_id3
event2      foo_id5     od_id9
event2      foo_id8     od_id10
event2      foo_id7     od_id11
event2      foo_id6     od_id12
event2      foo_id1     od_id4
event2      foo_id3     od_id5
event3      foo_id1     od_id6
event3      foo_id2     od_id7
event3      foo_id3     od_id8
```

Expected Output

```
event2  od_id1  1
event2  od_id2  1
event2  od_id3  1
event2  od_id4  1
event2  od_id5  1
event2  0d_id14 1
event2  od_id13 1
event2  od_id15 1
```

All events(ie, event1, event2, event3) have foo_ids. For all events in "event1", I would like to know how many times those foo_id(s) occur in event2 group by od_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is an "in clause" which you can use left semi join in Hive instead.

In your situation, you would create two tables:

```
create table log1 (id string, fooid string);
create table log2 (id string, fooid string, odid string);
```

and load your data into these tables.
The SQL command you need is

```
select id, odid, count(fooid)
from log2 left semi join log1 on (log1.fooid = log2.fooid)
where id = 'event2'
group by id, odid;
```